# Problem when adding Docs Module in Abp.io Project

Tags: abp

We have recently started to build our project on top of Abp.io. We follwed the instructions to create a new Blazor project like described in the guide https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Getting-Started-Create-Solution?UI=Blazor&DB=EF&Tiered=No and then tried to add the Docs Module to the project, https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Modules/Docs.

The problem is that during the installation of the module, using the CLI command abp add-module Volo.Docs something goes wrong and the module is not fully installed in the Blazor project. Below there is the screenshot of the error.

[CMD Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w53My.png)

And after 5 minutes the proccess continues and it finishes the install.

Is there a solution for the problem?

Comment: "...something goes wrong..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: I added more details. Hope that helps.